# how to get in game numerical input unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello i would like to know how to be able to enter data into a text box in unity. the following image shows what im talking about

[image]

In the image there are 3 input boxes for numbers, i would like to know how to create this in unity and take the numerical data from it .

Any help appreciated

Thanking You

Comment: Alan.. do you have any existing code..? have you checked out any of the `unity3d` tutorials or forums online..? they have a site that's similar to Stackoverflow [unity3d How can I](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/12321/how-can-i-start-learning-unity-fast-list-of-tutori.html)

Comment: friction = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), friction, 10);
that but i cant multiply stings

Comment: what you have displayed they are not strings they are ints what do you have friction defined as .. if they are indeed strings then you will need to convert the values to integers and Multiply them that way..

Comment: ??? float imafloat = System.Convert.ToSingle(friction)

Answer (score 1):

As i see you already have the

```
friction = GUI.TextField(new Rect(10, 10, 200, 20), friction, 10);
```

to be able to multiply your 3 values you will first need to convert them to a float or int

```
float mass = float.parse(friction);
```

This will convert it to a float that can be used for math

After you convert all 3 of them to a float or int you can use them in your calculation
if you want to show the outcome of this you can just turn the value back to a string by using toString()